# Вывести клавиатуру в эмуляторе Iphone Xcode Swift

Tags: swift, mobile-development

Никак не могу разобраться - делаю view регистрации. Как вывести клавиатуру в эмуляторе Iphone Xcode Swift?

Comment: как будто не вопрос задаёт, а милостыню просит.

Comment: Тебе делать нечего? Всякую фигню писать? Делом займись, тролль.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Широкая общественность](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420873/xcode-6-keyboard-does-not-show-up-in-simulator) утверждает, что если в симуляторе пойти в меню "Hardware" и там убрать галочку с "Connect Hardware Keyboard", то все получится.